# SQL to select randomly intercalated grouped results

Tags: sql, sqlite, random, group-by, sql-order-by

For a table that has ID and category columns we will have a category domain with 5 values, for example A, B, C, D and E.

We are using SQLite.

Our goal is to have a query that brings a number of intercalated grouped rows randomly selected and randomly sorted (inside each group of 5 rows), such as

```
ID    CAT
---   ---
076    C
753    D
503    A 
081    B 
335    E

475    B
643    D
995    A
105    E
549    C

553    E
871    B
064    C
720    D
119    A
```

The example above shows 3 groups os results, whose rows were randomly selected and whose sorting is also random.

Currently we are pulling the results using 5 queries (one for each category), and then sorting everything on application code.

SELECT * FROM table WHERE cat = 'A' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 3;

We will appreciate it if someone suggests a better solution by using a single query.

Comment: You can use UNION clause to issue a single query to the server, you can find an exaple [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-union/) @rubens-amaral

Comment: Thank you @DanIonescu for your suggestion, but what about my folded random requirement? I'm sorry, but using UNION I can't figure out how to achieve this.

Comment: Do you want for the 3 groups of results the categories to be unique each time, or maby B,D,A,C,B is acceptable @rubens-amaral?

Comment: Yes, every group should have unique categories, so B,D,A,C,B is unacceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use five temporary tables to assign [autoincrementing](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) IDs to the rows in each category:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE a(nr INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, id);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE b(nr INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, id);
...
INSERT INTO temp.a(id) SELECT id FROM MyTable WHERE cat = 'A' ORDER BY random();
INSERT INTO temp.b(id) SELECT id FROM MyTable WHERE cat = 'B' ORDER BY random();
...
```

Then you can combine the five tables so that the rows with the same `nr` values are sorted together:

```
SELECT nr, id, 'A' AS cat, random() AS r FROM temp.a
UNION ALL
SELECT nr, id, 'B',        random()      FROM temp.b
UNION ALL
...
ORDER BY nr, r;
```

Comment: Hi @CL, thank you for your suggestion, but the "ORDER BY nr, random()" is rising an error "2nd ORDER BY term does not match any column in the result set". I opened a new question about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284268/how-to-mix-asc-and-random-on-sqlite-order-by

Comment: Oops; fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query with 3 unions, it's not very short but it does it's job:

```
SELECT randomized.id, randomized.cat
FROM (
    SELECT randomized.id, randomized.cat
    FROM (
        SELECT id,cat FROM `table_test` ORDER BY RANDOM() 
        ) AS randomized
    GROUP BY cat
    ORDER BY RANDOM()
    ) AS randomized
UNION ALL
SELECT randomized.id, randomized.cat
FROM (
    SELECT randomized.id, randomized.cat
    FROM (
        SELECT id,cat FROM `table_test` ORDER BY RANDOM() 
        ) AS randomized
    GROUP BY cat
    ORDER BY RANDOM()
    ) AS randomized
UNION ALL
SELECT randomized.id, randomized.cat
FROM (
    SELECT randomized.id, randomized.cat
    FROM (
        SELECT id,cat FROM `table_test` ORDER BY RANDOM() 
        ) AS randomized
    GROUP BY cat
    ORDER BY RANDOM()
    ) AS randomized
```

Comment: Thank you once again @DanIonescu. Actualy there should be no duplicate result row at all by the query. Your query prevents duplication inside each block, its ok, but as the UNION applyes, duplications may happen. Maybe there is no solution, its really a challenging.

We are trying to play with your suggestion using WHERE clauses and/or JOINS so that each block do not pull any more retrieved data pulled from previous block, but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Developed a way to get results we need: consecutives blocks of rows, each block with no 'cat' duplication, and no 'id' duplication at all.

It's more mathematical oriented than query oriented, but anyway it suits our needs.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE a(nr INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, sort, id, cat);

INSERT INTO temp.a(id, cat) SELECT id, cat FROM tabela WHERE cat = 'A' ORDER BY random() limit 3;
INSERT INTO temp.a(id, cat) SELECT id, cat FROM tabela WHERE cat = 'B' ORDER BY random() limit 3;
INSERT INTO temp.a(id, cat) SELECT id, cat FROM tabela WHERE cat = 'C' ORDER BY random() limit 3;
INSERT INTO temp.a(id, cat) SELECT id, cat FROM tabela WHERE cat = 'D' ORDER BY random() limit 3;
INSERT INTO temp.a(id, cat) SELECT id, cat FROM tabela WHERE cat = 'E' ORDER BY random() limit 3;

UPDATE temp.a SET sort=100 where nr=1;
UPDATE temp.a SET sort=92+(select abs(random()%(2))*16) where nr=4;
UPDATE temp.a SET sort=88+(select abs(random()%(4))*8) where nr=7;
UPDATE temp.a SET sort=86+(select abs(random()%(8))*4) where nr=10;
UPDATE temp.a SET sort=85+(select abs(random()%(16))*2) where nr=13;

UPDATE temp.a SET sort=200 where nr=2;
UPDATE temp.a SET sort=192+(select abs(random()%(2))*16) where nr=5;
UPDATE temp.a SET sort=188+(select abs(random()%(4))*8) where nr=8;
UPDATE temp.a SET sort=186+(select abs(random()%(8))*4) where nr=11;
UPDATE temp.a SET sort=185+(select abs(random()%(16))*2) where nr=14;

UPDATE temp.a SET sort=300 where nr=3;
UPDATE temp.a SET sort=292+(select abs(random()%(2))*16) where nr=6;
UPDATE temp.a SET sort=288+(select abs(random()%(4))*8) where nr=9;
UPDATE temp.a SET sort=286+(select abs(random()%(8))*4) where nr=12;
UPDATE temp.a SET sort=285+(select abs(random()%(16))*2) where nr=15;

SELECT id, cat FROM temp.a ORDER BY sort;

DROP TABLE a;
```