# How to mix ASC and RANDOM() on SQLite ORDER BY

Tags: sqlite, random, sql-order-by

So, I'm facing an error while trying to use ORDER BY for 2 columns:

...
ORDER BY val, random();

Error is: "2nd ORDER BY term does not match any column in the result set"

I tried different ways to combine ASC sorting for 1st column and random sorting for second column, no luck.

UPDATED to provide more info

CREATE TABLE `tabela` (
    `id`    INTEGER,
    `val`   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);

```
INSERT INTO tabela (val) VALUES ('paid');
INSERT INTO tabela (val) VALUES ('paid');
INSERT INTO tabela (val) VALUES ('paid');
INSERT INTO tabela (val) VALUES ('standard');
INSERT INTO tabela (val) VALUES ('standard');
INSERT INTO tabela (val) VALUES ('standard');
INSERT INTO tabela (val) VALUES ('standard');
INSERT INTO tabela (val) VALUES ('standard');
```

Expected sample result:

```
val        id
---        ---
paid       3
paid       1
paid       2
standard   5
standard   8
standard   4
standard   6
standard   7
```

where 'id' 1,2,3 will be randomly sorted within 'paid' 'val' and 'id' 4 ... 8 will be randomly sorted within 'standard' 'val'

Comment: `order by a, b` does not mean to sort one column by a and one column by b. You will always sort complete rows. First sorting key is a, for identical a, the second key b is evaluated. Please provide an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  For SQLite that includes a dump, i.e. a text with at least one "CREATE TABLE" and several "INSERT INTO" lines, so that we can recreate your example structure and sample input. Give a code example which does sort two columns by different keys other than "random()" (i.e. prove me wrong).

Comment: Hi @Yunnosch, thank you for your attention. I'm sorry about being not "Complete". I posted a question update, hope my MCV now is ok.

Comment: Are "paid" and "standard" fixed strings? Can I hard-code them in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select val, id from (select random() as r, * from tabela) order by val, r;`

The trick is to make an on-the-fly table (inside the `(...)`) which has a column with random values. It is possible to order by that.
Note that this query is sorting/ordering complete rows of that on-the-fly table.

Output 1:

```
paid|1  
paid|3  
paid|2  
standard|8  
standard|5  
standard|7  
standard|6  
standard|4
```

Output 2:

```
paid|3  
paid|1  
paid|2  
standard|5  
standard|8  
standard|7  
standard|4  
standard|6
```

Please excuse my impression that you think of ordering columns. It might help you to see the difference, if you use only the subquery in the `(...)`, study the output and then imagine "manually" sorting the rows, while not being allowed to change any of the rows.

This is the query making the on-the-fly table (with additional ordering):

```
select random() as r, * from tabela order by val, id;
```

And its output:

```
6112298175921944810|1|paid  
-750320757383183987|2|paid  
-4687754812847362857|3|paid  
574487853771424670|4|standard  
6662074554381494613|5|standard  
5947282373212186891|6|standard  
-695595223160523440|7|standard  
-6914056362765123037|8|standard
```

Comment: Yes @Yunnosch, it solved the question, thank you.
I was also trying
"select id, val from tabela where val='paid' order by random()
union all
select id, val from tabela where val='standard' order by random();"
which rises the same error type as the one I first faced.